# Executable cannot find dynamically linked mkl library, but ldd does

Tags: linker, intel-mkl, ldd

I have a code which was dynamically linked with the mkl library. when running the code, it reports mkl not found.

```
./bmdl
/g/software/EMTO/5.7/intel_12.1/ser/bin/bmdl: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But when I use ldd to check the dynamically linked libraries in the executable, it shows the mkl library is found

```
ldd bmdl
libmkl_intel_lp64.so => /g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so (0x00002b975d76d000)
libmkl_sequential.so => /g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so (0x00002b975df53000)
libmkl_core.so => /g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so (0x00002b975e631000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003785600000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003784e00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003784a00000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000378a600000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003785200000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003784600000)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Output from `readelf -l ./bmdl`

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x4034b0
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001c0 0x00000000000001c0  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000400200 0x0000000000400200
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000e4eb4 0x00000000000e4eb4  R E    200000
  ....
```

More debugging

```
$ export LD_DEBUG=libs,files
$ ./bmdl
./bmdl: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ ldd ./bmdl
     15133: 
     15133: file=libtermcap.so.2 [0];  needed by /bin/sh [0]
     15133: find library=libtermcap.so.2 [0]; searching
     15133:  search path=/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/tls/x86_64:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/tls:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64/x86_64:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/mkl/lib/intel64:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/lib/intel64/tls/x86_64:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/lib/intel64/tls:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/lib/intel64/x86_64:/g/software/intelXE/composer_xe_2011_sp1/lib/intel64        (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
     ....
```

Seems `LD_DEBUG` doesn't have effect on running `./bmdl` alone.

I just realized the old `bmdl` has a 'setgid' flag and my new built doesn't have it. Maybe that was the cause?

```
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root gants 1123992 Jul 23 16:14 /scratch/helpdesk/bmdl
```

I removed the `setgid` bit from the old `bmdl` and running `./bmdl` doesn't complain about library not found. Now the question is why setgid can interfere with dynamically linked library?

It happens that setgid with a dynamically linked executable can cause security problems and is greatly limited by GNU glibc. For example, LD_LIBRARY_PATH will be ignored. Maybe the old built never worked before?!

Comment: can you provide the cmd line to show how you compile and link your `bmdl`?

Comment: The command line for linking MKL is as `-L$(MKLPATH) -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lpthread`. I omitted some detail here. `bmdl` was build first by somebody else and it worked. A few month later, we found it complained about the mkl library not found. So I rebuilt  it with its original makefile. The new build works. But I just feel it is very strange why the original build wouldn't work, especially `ldd` could resolve all dynamically linked libraries.

Comment: it's strange. which compiler/linker do you use? providing the whole complie/link cmd line in your orignal post may help. you can also try static linking.

Comment: Eric, I used the `Intel XE 12.1.5.339 compiler` and `GNU ld version 2.17.50.0.6-12.el5 20061020`. I doubt it is a problem of the compiler or the linker since I build `bmdl` again and the new one works fine. I just feel strange about the old `bmdl` and I am worried there may be some inconsistency in our system.

Comment: You mentioned your program was built long time ago. Maybe during this time compiler/linker has been updated, and you didn't clean your project before a new build. Then some of your obj are built by a different version of compiler. Then problem occurs.

Comment: @Eric The old built was done in fact two or three months ago. I also used the same compiler and linker for the new built.

Comment: @Eric We did install a new version of compiler. But I used the old compiler for building `bmdl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is dynamically linked and has the setgid attribute. setgid with a dynamically linked executable can cause security problems and is greatly limited by GNU glibc. For example, LD_LIBRARY_PATH will be ignored. That is why the code keeps on complaining some shared library not found.

Answer (score 7):

Using MKL reqires env variables including INCLUDE, MKLROOT, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, CPATH, FPATH and NLSPATH being properly set.

This can be done by a single script provided by Intel.

If you use intel compiler,

```
  $ source ${intel_dir}/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

If you use MKL only with gcc compiler,

```
  $ source ${intel_dir}/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

You can add this cmd line to your `.bashrc` so you don't need to run it every time.

Comment: Eric, thanks for your reply. All the environment variables have been properly set before I ran the executable.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I use ldd to check the dynamically linked libraries in the executable, it shows the mkl library is found

It is highly improbable that you've told us the whole story, because `ldd` (on Linux) is just a small shell script around `ld-linux.so`. If `ld-linux.so` can find the shared library when invoked by `ldd`, `ld-linux.so` should *also* be able to do that when the executable is invoked directly (`ld-linux.so` is what *actually* maps shared libraries when you run `a.out`).

The only plausible explanations I can think of:

- you execute `bmdl` in a different environment from the one you execute `ldd` in, or
- you have a modified `ldd` on your `PATH`, which perhaps modifies the environment before running "real" `ldd`.

> How do I know which linker is used?

```
readelf -l bmdl
```

and look for "Requesting program interpreter".

> `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2].`

Very strange.

The next debugging suggestion: set `LD_DEBUG=libs,files` and see where `ld-linux` is searching. You can do that for both `ldd` and `bmdl`, and see where the difference comes from.

Comment: When I launched `bmdl` using `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, the code actually ran to completion. This makes me wander there maybe something wrong with the OS on our cluster. Any idea what to proceed with the debugging. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I read the manpage of ld.so, which says   The dynamic linker can be run either indirectly through  running  some dynamically  linked  program  or library (in which case no command line options to the dynamic linker can be passed and, in the ELF  case, the dynamic linker which is stored in the .interp section of the program is executed)`    I checked the `.interp` section of `bmdl`, it is as follows:    `  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400200  0000000000400200  00000200  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
`     How do I know which linker is used?

Comment: I got "[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]". This should be right. But why when running 'bmdl' alone I still get libmkl_intel_lp64.so not found?

Comment: `export LD_DEBUG=libs,files` only works for `ldd ./bmdl`, and doesn't show any debugging information to `./bmdl`.

Comment: I just found the old built `bmdl` has the setgid flag `-rwxr-sr-x 1 root gants 1123992 Jul 23 16:14 ./bmdl` and after I remove the flag from the old `bmdl`, running `./bmdl` doesn't complain about library not found. Then the question is how setgid can interfere with shared libraries?

Comment: It appears setgid with a dynamically linked executable can cause security problems and is greatly limited by GNU glibc.